# Intersections of Noetherian regular local rings of finite Krull dimensions

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, local-rings

Let us consider Noetherian regular local rings $R_i$ of finite Krull-dimensions for each $i \geq 1$ such that 
\begin{equation*}
R_1 \supset R_2 \supset \cdots
\end{equation*}
Suppose each embedding $\psi_{ij} \colon R_j \hookrightarrow R_i$ is faithfully flat for any $j > i$.

### Q. Is $\bigcap R_i \colon= R_{\infty}$ a coherent ring?